# what is the csh equivalent of set -xv?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, csh

I have a rather long csh script that doesnt work, or doesnt work properly. in bash I would do `set -xv` to get verbose logging. what can I do in cshell? I tried adding `set -xv` it complained that `-` isnt allowed, and `set xv` didnt do anything.

Comment: I do have to point it out : there is a famous Usenet era post "Csh programming considered harmful", and this explicit faq entry : http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/  ... If you can afford it : try to stick to posix sh, if possible at all ? (I know it is not an answer to your question, but I felt obligated to point csh flaws out)

Comment: I didnt write it man, Im just trying to use some code, and theyre all hell bent on using csh. I tried rewriting their spaghetti code into bash, but it still didnt work, and theyve got arbout 1000 files in 6 languages. Im not going to be rewriting the entire code base. Im just trying to install vmd on an ARM platform

Comment: I do feel your pain... try to convince them with the above articles. Meanwhile: you can maybe try to use :  https://www.shellcheck.net/  ?  (it is maybe not Csh-compatible, but most of the code would be parsed and "linted" and will highlight problematic sections)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
csh -xv script
```

or you can add

```
set verbose
set echo
```

to your script.

Answer (score 2):

read the man page! `man csh` oops, well, I when I call the script I ran `$csh -x -v ./script`
which set verbose mode. actually it has stayed in verbose mode beyond the execution of the one script, but I guess thats fine.